# operator<< does not match

Tags: c++, stream, operators

I have a code snippet like this:

```
class track {

public:

struct time {
    unsigned minutes, seconds;

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o) {
        o << minutes << "minute(s) " << seconds << " second(s)";
        return o;
    }
};

...

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o) {
    o << "title: " << title << " performer: " << performer << " length: " << length << std::endl;
    return o;
}

private:
std::string performer, title;
time length;
};
```

However, if i compile this code, i got this error:

```
no match for 'operator<< ...'
```

Could you tell me what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Hint: you're defining `std::ostream& operator<<(time&, std::ostream& o)`. Is that the right order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your object `obj` of class `T` to support typical streaming (e.g. `cout << obj`) you have to define an operator at global scope:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const T& obj) {
  ...
}
```

(if the function needs to access private fields, you can declare it as a friend)

If, as in your code, you declare an operator as a member

```
std::ostream& T::operator<<(std::ostream& o)
```

you are esentially defining this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(T& obj, std::ostream& o)
```

and you can use it like this: `obj << cout`, but that is probably not what you want!

Comment: Ahh, i wanted to shorten my code by not defining globals. I should have remembered that won't work. Thanks!

Comment: It is not a `const T&`, just a `T&`.

Comment: You should use `const T&` because `<<` operator is not supposed to change the `obj`, and secondly because otherwise it won't work for temporary `T` objects.

Comment: @CygnusX1, I believe Pubby meant the last code block. The function is not marked `const`, so the `this` parameter is non-const as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the operators as a non-member functions:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const track::time& t) {
    return o << t.minutes << "minute(s) " << t.seconds << " second(s)";
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const track& t) {
    return o << "title: " << t.title << " performer: " << t.performer << " length: " << t.length;
}
```

You would have to make the latter a `friend` in order to access the private data members.

Answer (score 1):

You want to have this operator outside of your class:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const track &t) {
    return o << "title: " << t.title() << " performer: " << t.performer()
      << " length: " << t.length() << std::endl;
}
```

And, of course, you need to add appropriate getter functions to your class `track`, or, alternatively, make the operator a friend of the class `track` so it can access the `track`'s private members directly.

Comment: Make it a friend. Making it a friend will not break encapsulation unlike getter functions that do break encapsulation.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99589/what-is-friend-keyword-used-for/99595#99595

Comment: @LokiAstari: I beg to differ.  By making it a friend and not providing getters, you've simply given me a really inconvenient way to create my own global getters.  Because I can write a global getter function that uses your friend operator to output the data to an `ostringstream`, then parses the string.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Sure you can abuse the interface in any way you like. But getter expose internal details of the class. A stream operator exposes a serialized version of the object (there is a difference here). The interface to the serialized version of the object provides no guarantees to what is on the stream. The only thing that you can get is that it will de-serialize correctly with the `operator >>` (if one is provided) and potentially is human readable (but no guarantees). A correctly serialized object will contain version information to help this processes.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: In short there are no good reasons for getters (there is nearly always a better solution). Trying to build global getters using the serialized version of an object is a hack that is very fragile and bound to break in the future.

Comment: @LokiAstari: If there is a better solution, the one you are referring to is definitely not it.  If you're writing a class which represents an audio track, why would you deny the users of that class direct access to information like the title, the performer and the length of the track?

Comment: @another option is to give the class a public method `std::ostream& foo(std::ostream&);`, and call that from the non-member `std::ostream& operator<<`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: This is definitely not the solution to that problem (as this is a question about serialization). But I would ask why anybody need access to this information and then define the appropriate methods to provide the correct information in the context to which the class was being used (which is unlikely to be a getter (but could be)). Unfortunately that question is way to vague (as you know) to be answered without the context of the surrounding code.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Yes getters are simple and convenient. Unfortunately they have a nasty tendency to bind your implementation into a specific way of doing things that ultimately makes your code inflexible and brittle. As a result you should tend to avoid them if there is a better solution (and interfaces to solve specific problems). This is not always possible at which point you bite the bullet.

Comment: @LokiAstari: I tend to agree with that.  But in this specific example, even though we don't have all the details, I am quite convinced that getters are completely appropriate. http://ideone.com/Tiwcd0

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I think not. Since I would not want to bind myself to an implementation they are completely wrong for this stage in the processes.

Comment: @LokiAstari: I don't see how adding getters binds you to an implementation more than `operator<<` does. http://ideone.com/p8piML

Comment: I think a way to think about the operator<< is like it is part of the class it's printing, although it is technically a free function.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: operator<< does not bind you to anything. It allows you to use a stream nothing about the implementation becomes unchangeable. But one you provide the `Date Song::getArtistBirthday()` you will have a hard time removing that method from the class after the first person uses that method (Even if that data is no longer sensible to retrieve via the song). Unless you are talking about the binding of operator<< and operator>> which is fair (It is hard but not imposable you just have to be careful in how you define your serialization format and make sure it contains version info).